# How to enumerate the privileges of a user account obtained from group membership?

Tags: c++, winapi, local-security-policy, local-security-authority

I can get the privileges of a user account through the API LsaEnumerateAccountsWithUserRight.
But this function ignores the privileges inherited as part of a group membership.
msdn documentation clearly mentions [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms721792(v=vs.85).aspx)

> The accounts returned by this function hold the specified privilege
>   directly through the user account, not as part of membership to a
>   group.

Is it possible to get this done in windows? 
Any guidance is appreciated.

Comment: You cannot get the privileges of a user account using `LsaEnumerateAccountsWithUserRight`. The API call returns accounts that have a particular user right applied. The privileges of an account are queried using [`LsaEnumerateAccountRights`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms721790.aspx) instead.